# Strings of arrays and maps?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table that contains a field of a varchar type. Within this field, there are empty arrays, arrays and maps stored as strings. something like this:

| id | dumped_field |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [] |
| 2 | [123,456,789] |
| 3 | {'0":123, "1":456} |
| 4 | NULL |

The goal would be to try and convert this string field as an array as opposed to a string:

| id | dumped_field |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [] |
| 2 | [123,456,789] |
| 3 | [123,456] |
| 4 | NULL |

The problem is that these various data types have been stored as strings into this field. Is there a way to A) convert the string of array into an array and B) convert the string of json into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is json (and after fixing the quotes in the object) you can process it as json (leveraging `try` and `try_cast`):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, dumped_field) AS (
   VALUES (1,   '[]'),
        (2, '[123,456,789]'),
        (3, '{"0":123, "1":456}'),
        (4, NULL)
)

-- query
select coalesce(
    try_cast(json_parse(dumped_field) as array(varchar)), --  try process as array
    try(map_values(cast(json_parse(dumped_field) as map(varchar, varchar)))))  --  try process as object
from dataset;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [] |
| [123, 456, 789] |
| [123, 456] |
| NULL |

Comment: Yes, it was a json struct but in our IDE it shows up without the quotes. Thanks for pointing that out. This coalesce/try_cast is neat. Thank you!